# Cookie banner, need I?

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I'm analyzing a wordpress website (I'm the developer) with this firefox plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/a-cookie-manager/. It says there are no cookies. Need I a cookie banner as well (such as iubenda cookie solution)?

Comment: *Need I a cookie banner as well (such as iubenda cookie solution)?* err, depends on your website audience whether you should put up a cookie usage banner or not. also, sorry for flagging this as it more into [webmaster](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), unrelated to programming at all.

Comment: Sorry for posting in the wrong section. Anyway I'll try to be more specific about my question: 1. Can I trust that firefox addon when it says there are non cookies on my wordpress wbsite? 2. If the answer is yes (no cookies form the website) may I avoid to put a cookie banner and being ok width EU law?

Comment: 1) no, if you use firefox, you could just CTRL+SHIFT+K and see on the storage tab, why bother with plugin if you have the Browser Console. 2) i'm not a lawyer so i cant give you an answer for that. though personally i'd go with giving the notice nevertheless. better safer than sued later.